# Using ChangeDetectorRef detach method with PrimeNg OverlayPanel

Tags: angular, primeng

We are using the detach method of ChangeDetectorRef to overcome some performance issues, and it has been working OK with most things, however it also prevents the OverlayPanel from PrimeNg from closing if clicking anywhere outside the OverlayPanel (dismissable is set to true). Example html:

```
<h2>PrimeNG Issue Template</h2>
<button style="width: 90vw" (click)="overlayPanel.toggle($event); detectChanges();" >Show</button>

<p-overlayPanel #overlayPanel [dismissable]="true" >
  <div style="width: 40vw">Overlay panel content</div> </p-overlayPanel>
```

Example code:

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   counter: number = 0;

   constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
       cd.detach();
   }

   ngOnInit() {
     this.detectChanges();
   }

   detectChanges() {
     this.cd.detectChanges();
   }

   onClick() {
      this.counter++;
   }
}
```

In Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/issue-primeng-template-2eb8hp

In the Stackblitz example, the OverlayPanel does not even render properly, but I thought I'd include it in case someone wants to play with it.

**EDIT**: Edited the HTML and code to make it a closer example to our situation.

Answer (score 0):

cd.detach() method detaches the view from the change-detection tree. A detached view is not checked until it is reattached (overlay is already detached view and there will never be reattachment). Use in combination with detectChanges() to implement local change detection checks.
therefore, in this case it wont be applied, still you can do it on click event instead of doing it in constructor.
for more details: https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#detach

Comment: I know how detach works; I'm just after a solution of how to make the OverlayPanel dismiss. I've updated the html/code in the question so it's a bit more "workable"

Comment: alternatively, you can use hostlistener for outside click event

Comment: Added a hostlistener in this StackBlitz updated for the most recent version of Angular: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zgeupw, which works (though the panel does not display correctly). Sadly, it does not work in our application - takes two clicks for some reason. Going to dig more, but thanks for your help.